# QuickBooks Online java SDK, Bill creation with nonexistent product

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I would like to create Bill on the fly with SDK. I have got huge product list in my proprietary application. I would like to add there product to bills as line item. Should I create product in QBO prior to creating bill or I'm able to add nonexistent products on the fly? Which is the easiest ways to create a bill if I don't want to load all of my services into QBO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I create product in QBO prior to creating bill

Yes.

> or I'm able to add nonexistent products on the fly?

No.

> Which is the easiest ways to create a bill if I don't want to load all of my services into QBO?

Create the service in QBO whenever it is needed by a bill.